# How to sync IE & Chrome behavior for flex CSS display

Tags: css, flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/Lc6f1ebL/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{position:relative;width:400px;padding:20px;background:yellow}
.inner{position:absolute;display:flex;background:red}
.box{height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black}
```

I am trying to create a container, whose position is absoluted, and some dynamic inner contents(div blocks) will be appended to it from time to time. I want this container’s width to be extended accordingly. For example, ‘.inner’ now has 5 children divs, and its width is 500px. When an identical ‘.box’ div is appended to ‘.inner’, ‘.inner’s width should be 600px. Of course, the '.box's' widths should also be dynmaic.
It seems to me this can easily (or only) be done by using flex display, but I’m having a cross-browser issue. In IE, the flex-container ‘.inner’ is forced to be confined within its parent, thus its width is not numberOfChildren * Children’s width. Is there anyway to overcome this?

Comment: if you want the box to keep it's size and make the .inner grow larger than outer then you can use this http://jsfiddle.net/Lc6f1ebL/5/

Comment: I think flex is still too young to be used. The result from your initial fiddle appears differently in chrome and firefox. I am sure you can achieve the same result not using flex